# Should I see my SmartTarget promotions in Fredhopper?

Tags: smarttarget

I created some promotions in SDL SmartTarget 2014, now I do not see them in the Fredhopper GUI, is that right?

Comment: I posted this self answered question cause I got the same question twice within two days.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default you will not see SmartTarget promotions in Fredhopper. Fredhopper users should not change the SmartTarget promotions in the Fredhopper GUI, so they are hidden.

If you are doing some troubleshooting or just are curious, you can change a setting in the SmartTarget extension in Fredhopper to enable the listing in the Fredhopper GUI.

Just add a [file](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/94bcf7d9c10ec04c8925) named [`smarttarget_api_extension.properties`](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/94bcf7d9c10ec04c8925) to the `FREDHOPPER_HOME\data\instances\SMARTARGET_INSTANCE\config directory`. The file should contain this configuration:

```
  visible=true
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-287608E8-1E7A-4BE5-9682-B84B8FB4B8E4) (login required) for details.

Comment: Just to drill it into people: do not, ever, modify the promotions within Fredhopper. It can mess up your SmartTarget -- hence why they are hidden by default. But it can indeed be useful to view them for troubleshooting purposes; just be sure to hide them again afterwards to remove the temptation to 'quickly change something'.

Comment: +1 for the useful comment @PeterKjaer. Honestly I never felt tempted to change a promotion in the Fredhopper GUI, the Targeting GUI in the CME is much easier to use! :)

Comment: What about changing the sort order? That is easy to do in FH and not possible in SmartTarget, I believe. Would that really mess up SmartTarget?

Comment: Note that in the path that Jan supplied, the 'indexer' is just the name of the SmartTarget instance. It can be anything, for us it is 'SmartTarget'. So the path is really <FREDHOPPER_HOME>\data\instances\<SMARTTARGET_INSTANCE>\config

Comment: Changing the priority in Fredhopper does not change the priority in SmartTarget. The SmartTarget query api determines its own priority. The SmartTarget priority is stored in a special meta promotion in Fredhopper.

Comment: Thanks for your comment about the Fredhopper instance name, I updated the answer.